# Sony Camera API: What state events should happen after calling actTakePicture

Tags: android, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Reading the Sony camera API reference it states that I should see the following events after calling actTakePicture:

Camera status: "IDLE" -> "StillCapturing" -> "StillSaving" -> "IDLE"

I never see the StillSaving event. For me it seems to go from IDLE --> StillCapture --> IDLE.

Also it seems that even though the camera gives an event of IDLE if I then call actTakePicture straight away there is a significant delay before the camera responds, suggesting that the camera itself is in some kind of busy state and not IDLE as the last event seemed to indicate.

Could anyone from Sony help and explain why I'm not seeing the StillSaving event and why there seems to be a significant delay when taking subsequent images even though the cameras last status is IDLE.

I've tried this with two cameras the QX10 and A5000.

Comment: Does anyone from Sony ever check stackoverflow? It says on their website that stackoverflow is the place to get support from them. But I see very little input from Sony here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following status ("IDLE" -> "StillCapturing" -> "StillSaving" -> "IDLE") is typical sequence, but some cameras may skip “StillSaving” state. Regarding the delay, the camera needs to prepare for the next shot and the camera will start capturing as soon as possible. As you might expect the amount of light available, auto-focusing time, processor, storage speed, etc may additionally affect the time between shots.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team

Comment: Great, thanks for the response. Knowing that this is only a typical sequence helps. Though I'm still a little confused as to why the camera would give an IDLE status, when it appears that it is not idle?  Maybe a future firmware update on cameras could fix this? It just seems that the cameras are reporting that they are idle to early. Maybe another state like READY, might be a good thing?

Comment: Thank you. I will forward it to the dev team.

Comment: Good to hear. I've been working on a range of features and ideas with the camera API. If the dev team ever want more feedback or input I'd be very happy to talk with them.